# Test driven development on front end?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, front-end, angular

When reading through internet, I've seen people are really into testing the front end applications. Some of them also say that they will never hire someone on front end who doesn't have testing experience.

I understand that testing is necessary when dealing with huge amount of computation, logic and intertwined modules, which is most of the time not the case with front end development. The project I'm working on will have a couple of modules like that, and I would write the tests for that, but what to do with the rest of the app?

For example my current task is to create an AuthGuard service, and my project lead explicitly said that I need to write tests for it. While looking into it I found **so many** examples that are useless in my opinion.

For example I came across this function:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

being tested this way:

```
it('should return true for a logged in user', () => {
  authService = { isLoggedIn: () => true };
  router = new MockRouter();
  authGuard = new AuthGuard(authService, router);

  expect(authGuard.canActivate()).toEqual(true);
});
```

Well, no way, Sherlock! Obviously it's going to return true when there is an if statement, because that is how if statements work. And this is not the worse I've seen. I've seen a person creating a mock service, and mock api call with the same data and comparing the two.

I'm writing to check if there is something wrong with majority of our industry, or it just could be me? Did the test driven development gain too much attention and everyone is writing articles about how to do it while not mentioning that maybe we don't need it?

Comment: Are you saying tests aren't valuable if they pass? Sure, it's obvious that the code will do what the test says it should, but that's *good* - the test will pass. And if someone changes it in the future such that it doesn't, the test will fail and they'll find out. You'd also have another test that it returns false if the service does, *with the appropriate side effect*, so the behaviour of the system under test is: 1. described; and 2. protected from regressions. Now you can refactor it and be confident that it still does what it's supposed to afterwards.

Comment: ... or, if the behaviour changes, update the test for the new behaviour and know when you've successfully changed the code to implement it. Not that people can't also write low value tests that are e.g. too coupled to the current implementation (very frequent) or even only exercise test doubles, not the system that's supposed to be under test (I've seen this, too), but that doesn't mean that all tests are low value, and the one you show seems fine.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not saying they are not valuable, I'm saying they are useless in these conditions, when the functions are straightforward, which is the case with most of the front end functions.

Comment: There are other levels to test at, e.g. you could use browser drivers to exercise the front end, but you lose granularity over where the problem is, when one occurs, if you *only* have those high-level tests. Also if you have a rule like "simple functions don't need unit tests" then how does "simple" get defined, how do you decide when it's become sufficiently complex to warrant introducing tests, and how do you ensure the code is written such that doing so is easy once you get there? Do you only write a test for the second case, which *doesn't* just return a boolean?

Comment: Also it's only obvious the code does that because the code exists. With TDD, that test was written *before* the code existed, and described the *intended* behaviour. Maybe the first version of the method was just `return true`, with the conditional only being added once a second test said it should return false and redirect when the user's not logged in.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think "simple" doesn't have to be defined, I think it should be up to developers when they think they need test, and that would be 'when we think it can save us some time', while usually testing requires sometimes more time than writing a function, when dealing with some mock data, and thats why I think sometimes enforcing TDD might be an overkill.

The second point I totally understood, thank you.

Comment: Then you have to reconcile different opinions on simplicity - what seems simple to you may not be so to another person on the team (particularly if they're new to the team). The problem with the time saving approach is that writing a test doesn't necessarily save you time in the moment of writing the code. Tests are an investment in the future ability to refactor code to add new features without introducing regressions, or to quickly triangulate and fix a bug. Here's one explanation of [why TDD](https://builttoadapt.io/why-tdd-489fdcdda05e) (disclaimer: I also work for VMware Pivotal Labs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Adversarial vs Aspirational

I think this is the problem you've tripped over.

In TDD the process is this:

1. Write an Aspirational test describing the behaviour desired.
2. Write the code in the unit that makes this test pass, while keeping the other tests passing.
3. Review the Aspirations and make sure they are what you aspire too.
4. Update your Aspirations
5. Repeat

When your boss/manager/team lead is turning around and saying that it should be tested (in the context of TDD) they are talking about these Aspirational tests. In this methodology it makes sense to write a test that describes happy and unhappy paths even for the most trivial of cases - because these aren't tests. They are a design document. Perhaps it is better to think of them as self-checking properties.

However I suspect you are instead hearing that you should write the other kind of test - the adversarial kind.

In this kind of test you look at general knowledge (check box testing), the spec (black box testing) or the actual implementation (white box testing) and you hunt for actual weak points.

- A check box test for example would fuzz an input field. Not because you know anything specific about it, but because it is a general attack that might happen, and you want to make sure the system can handle it.
- A black box test might for example see what happens when you `pop()` and `empty()` stack. Does it behave right? What if it was quadruple `pop()`ed?
- A white box test will look for that one statement that dereferences a `null`, or sets up an infinite loop, and proves that there is a problem here.

In which case, testing that `if` is just a non-starter. It doesn't make sense, an `if(bool)` is guaranteed to work. If it doesn't there is an issue with the platform/compiler not the code itself. (Which might be useful to know, but isn't the point either).

---

It is always easier to write Aspirational tests up-front. Otherwise it feels like you are rehashing the implementation, and it feels like you are just Yes Manning the whole thing.

If you are put in such a position, try to ignore the implementation. Read the user stories, or look at the users of the function (not the function itself). Cobble together the expectations, this paints the acceptability picture from both a business (from story) and usage (from code that calls it) perspective. This helps to keep the tests away from prescribing an implementation. It also helps with the Yes Man feeling.

Adversarial tests on the other hand can only be written against an implementation. By which I mean, that you only know how to attack it once something is known about it.

- Once it is decided that the input is a textbox, then you can write ways to attack it.
- Once you know the semantics of the interface, you can write ways to attack it.
- Once you have an implementation to examine, you can write ways to attack it.

If you are tasked with writing them be aware of the depth of the attack you can provide at this point in the development process. Also be aware of your own attachment to the work, if you are overly attached it will lead to tests that coddle the code instead of revealing its weaknesses.

- If it's your own code - If possible leave time between when you implement it, and when you attack it (several months is a good start).
- leverage a check list of general issues, tailor it with knowledge about the dev who wrote it (if that's yourself honestly record and generalise the issues you tend to make).
- get someone else to have a go at the code. (and add those issues to the list).
- look at the tests already written and ask if the test would reveal something by going one step further.
- look at logs of known issues in the system, they are the breadcrumb trails of successful adversaries.